# undefined method `state_id' for #<Form:0x4107ea0>

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using [this](http://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/) guide to create dynamic dropdown selection.

I finished up all code stuff. But instead of using Country and City models I used Region and State.
i want to use this selection in forms/_form.html.erb, but this form I am rendering into Home index view.

**state.rb**

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region

  attr_accessible :name, :region_id
end
```

**Home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @form = Form.new
    @regions = Region.all
    @states = State.where("region_id = ?", State.first.id)
  end

  def show
    @state = State.find_by("id = ?", params[:form][:state_id])
  end

  def update_states
    @states = State.where("region_id = ?", params[:region_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :form, url: {action: "show"}, html: {method: "get"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :region_id, options_for_select(@regions.collect { |region|
    [region.name.titleize, region.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'regions_select' } %>
  <%= f.select :state_id, options_for_select(@states.collect { |state|
    [state.name.titleize, state.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'states_select' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Go!" %>
<% end %>
```

Problem occurs in 4 line:

```
<%= f.select :state_id, options_for_select(@states.collect { |state| ...
```

If I remove this statement it works great. But now I get this errot:

```
undefined method `state_id' for #<Form:0x4107ea0>
```

Comment: what is `Form`? if it someting valid and has `state_id` maybe you could try replace `:form` to `@form`? also are you sure that `"region_id = ?", State.first.id` shouldn't be `"region_id = ?", @regions.first.id`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

```
collection_select(:form, :state_id, State.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no change. I think the problem is in controller. `@states = State.where("region_id = ?", State.first.id)`

Comment: Hmm. Try to use `@state = State.all`

Comment: I found mistake was that I missed state_id column in Forms table :)